# How to output Unknown number of element to standard container

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have the following function:

```
template <class Titerator>
void detect_corners(cv::Mat const& frame, Titerator begin_corners);
```

It was supposed to output 4 and just 4 corners into the `begin_corners`. So, everything were ok and easy. However, the requirement changed, it may now return any number of corners. What is the best way to deal with this without losing generalization?. I mean I do not want to make use always vector instead of general iterator.

P.S. When calling this function, I do not know how many corners I will get. The function should run and then it knows.

Comment: You think there's a problem. That's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use an [OutputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator). No need to change your declaration, but I gave names that illustrate the requirement of the iterator being an OutputIterator.

```
template <class IterOut>
void detect_corners(cv::Mat const& frame, IterOut out) {
    while(condition) {
        *out++ = whatever;
    }
}
```

You can get an output iterator for any standard container. For example, a back inserter for vector:

```
std::vector<T> v;
detect_corners(frame, std::back_inserter(v));
```

Comment: *out++ ,, Will this cause any problem if I used not contiguous container like list? is not std::next better here or am I missing sth?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi it's completely fine to increment an iterator to non-contiguous container. The difference between increment operator and `std::next` is that `std::next` does not modify the original iterator, but returns an incremented copy. Since there is no need for the output iterator to be `const`, there is no reason to use `std::next`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has an `OutputIterator` concept, which allows you to pass in an iterator which you can use for writing to. An example of how you could accept this in your function:

```
template <typename OutputIterator>
void detect_corners(const cv::Mat &frame, OutputIterator it) {
    for (/* each corner */) {
        it = corner; // Assigning to an OutputIterator
                     // appends an element to the container.
    }
}
```

You then need to create an `OutputIterator` compatible iterator to pass to your function  - to do this for vector:

```
detect_corners(frame, std::back_inserter(my_vector));
```

You can also create an `OutputIterator` for different containers, for more information see the [OutputIterator concept documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator).